# Need to replace column value in scala spark

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I have a json data stored as string column in spark dataframe and it has some bad data
Ex:

```
{"name":"neo",
 "age":"22",
 "city""nowhere",
 "country":""}
```

I need to transform the column value to add "city":"nowhere". I tried the following but it's not working as expected. What should I change to get this working

```
val regex = """(".*?")(".*?")"""
df.withColumn("updated_col", regexp_replace(col("value"), regex, "$1:$2"))
```

Comment: Are you sure the replacement backreference syntax is  `$n` here? Try `"\\1:\\2"` instead.

Comment: I tried replacing and it didn't work

Comment: can you please add input & expected output ? are you simply replacing without any conditions ? also what is bad data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below solution

```
scala> df
.withColumn(
    "updated", 
    regexp_replace(
        $"data",
         """[^:]("")""",
         """\":\""""
    )
)
.show(false)
+------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|data                                                  |updated                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|{"name":"neo","age":"22","city""nowhere","country":""}|{"name":"neo","age":"22","cit":"nowhere","country":""}|
+------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
scala> df
.withColumn(
     "updated", 
     regexp_replace(
        $"data", 
        """"city""nowhere"""", 
        """"city":"nowhere""""
     )
)
.show(false)
+------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|data                                                  |updated                                                |
+------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|{"name":"neo","age":"22","city""nowhere","country":""}|{"name":"neo","age":"22","city":"nowhere","country":""}|
+------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to limitations in Spark's regexp_replace (or perhaps my limitations of understanding it), the only way I managed to do it involves a two-step process using a temporary unique delimiter shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import spark.implicits._ 
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JsonFix").master("local[1]").getOrCreate()
    


val df = Seq(
      (1, """{"name":"neo", "age":"22", "city""nowhere", "country":""}""")
    ).toDF("id", "value")

df.show(false)

// Introduce a temporary unique delimiter to isolate "city" segments
val tmpDelimiter = "___TMP___"
val df1 = df.withColumn("value", regexp_replace(col("value"), "\"city\"\"", "\"city\"" + tmpDelimiter + "\""))

// adding missing ':' for "city" using the temporary delimiter
val df2 = df1.withColumn("value", regexp_replace(col("value"), "\"city\"" + tmpDelimiter, "\"city\":"))
df2.show(false)
```

I would be interested to know however another way of managing this too.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that uses json and map spark functions. I have tested it.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{from_json,col, map_concat, expr, to_json}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{MapType, StringType}

val jsonString="""{"name":"neo","age":"22","country":""}"""
val data = Seq((1, jsonString))
val df=data.toDF("id","value")
df.show(truncate = false)
val df2 = df.withColumn("value", to_json(map_concat(expr("""map("city", "nowhere")"""), from_json(col("value"),MapType(StringType,StringType)))))
df2.show(truncate = false)
```

Output:

```
+---+--------------------------------------------+
|id |value                                       |
+---+--------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"name":"neo",\n "age":"22",\n "country":""}|
+---+--------------------------------------------+

+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
|id |value                                                  |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"city":"nowhere","name":"neo","age":"22","country":""}|
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
```